# Questions concerning CSS and the YAML in R

Tags: html, css, r, margin

First, I know that one can use CSS in order to format things in the YAML. Through some trial and error, have discovered that the title in the sample YAML below is an h1. The subtitle is under p. Trying to have the title and subtitle be right on top of each other with minimal space. I have tried a variety of things. Such as adjusting padding-bottom and margin-bottom (for the title) and padding-top and margin-top (for the subtitle). Also, added line height to both sections and it does not solve the issue. I have read that you can do something with div tags but am unsure how I would go about this avenue. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. As for reproducible, this is the sample presentation that comes with R-Studio. File>new file>R markdown>ioslides.

```
   Something
   December 2020
```

At the moment it appears as such

```
  Something
   

  December 2020
```

This is the YAML as it stands now.

```
  title: Market Briefing
  subtitle: <span style="font-size:22px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; font- 
  weight:normal">December 2020</span><br></br>
  author: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A; float:left; 
  font-weight:normal">Analysis Bureau</span>
  date: <span style="font-size:18px; font-family:'Arial'; color:#0A0A0A;font-style:normal; 
  float:left">2/2/2021</span>
  output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
  css: styles.css


  Here is the CSS that I am using

  h1{
 font-family:'Arial';
 font-size:52px !important;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 margin:0px;
 margin-bottom:-1000em
 color: #0A0A0A;
 }

 p{
 font-family:"Arial";
 font-size:18px !important;
 padding-bottom:0px;
 padding-top:0px;
 margin-top:-100px;
 margin:1px;
 color: #0A0A0A;
 line-height:1;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) can be more sophisticated than just the element selector as you are using in your css file. For example, your css will style all `h1` elements throughout the document, but you might only be interested in styling the `h1` element on the title slide.

Do you know about the "inspect element" feature available in many browsers including the RStudio browser? This will help you identify ways you might reference the elements you wish to style. Most browsers offer this feature under the right click menu.

I would recommend to not include the inline css in your yaml. It is just as easy to include that in your css file and much cleaner that way provided you can identify a good css selector to use.

While I am unsure exactly what look you are trying to achieve, here is an attempt at implementing what you have shared. You may have to play around with this to get exactly what you are after.

First the css:

```
[data-config-title] {
  height: 60px;
}

[data-config-subtitle] {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  color: #0A0A0A;
  font-weight: normal
}

[data-config-presenter] {
  font-size: 18px; 
  font-family: 'Arial'; 
  color: #0A0A0A; 
  float:left; 
  font-weight: normal
}

body > slides > slide.title-slide.segue.nobackground.current > hgroup > p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 18px; 
  font-family: 'Arial'; 
  color: #0A0A0A;
  font-style: normal; 
  float: left;
}
```

In there I have used the css attribute selector to style your title, subtitle, and author elements. I have also used a much more complicated css selector to style your date since there is no uniquely identifying information for that element such as the attributes for the title, subtitle, and author elements had.

Your main question was about spacing between the title and subtitle elements and how you wished this space to be less. When using the inspect element feature, I was able to see that the padding, border, and margin around these elements are all set to 0. So I decided to change the height of the title element from 91px to 60px. This has the effect of moving the subtitle up as desired.

And now the RMarkdown:

````
---
title: Market Briefing
subtitle: December 2020
author: Analysis Bureau
date: 2/2/2021
output: 
  ioslides_presentation:
    css: styles.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide with Bullets

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

## Slide with R Output

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
````

And this produces a title slide that looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but I think that what i am looking for can't be done. It is not an HTML or CSS item.. not really.

Comment: This should probably just be a comment on the question, rather than an answer